# error when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use the [iTunes search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), it requires you to dynamically place script tags in your code to handle the problem with cross origin resource sharing. I'm using ng-repeat to place these tags in the markup

```
<div ng-repeat="x in scripts">
  <script ng-src={{x}}></script>
</div>
```

and in my app.js file, I have this

```
$scope.scripts = [];
$scope.find = function(search) {
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent($scope.search);
  var fullSearch = itunesURL + 'term=' + encoded + '&country=US&media=music&limit=5&callback=songhandler';
  $scope.scripts.push(fullSearch); 
}
```

But I'm getting an error in the console log when I test it.

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr]
```

Empty script tags are being placed without a `src` attribute.
[image: errors]

[image: errors]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your interpolation code remove this line from your code

```
<div ng-repeat="x in scripts">
  <!--<script ng-src="{{x}}"></script>-->
</div>
```

Comment: How will the scripts get injected then?

Comment: @Rockstar5645 your error is occurring due to interpolation problem not from **`ngRepeat`** as far as I understand. So you first check that. For interpolation problem you can set breakpoints & watch in developer tools & check for which value it's causing problem & then provide that data so that we can help you.

Comment: I added the errors I'm getting. and I removed the quotes around `{{x}}`

Comment: @Rockstar5645 can you provide **`scripts`** value when the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem?  Missing quotes in your script tag?

```
<script ng-src="{{x}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) helped me do what I wanted to do.